# How do I convert a ZipFile object to an object supporting the buffer API?

Tags: python, object, binary, python-zipfile

I have a ZipFile object that I need to convert to an object that will work with the buffer api. Context is that I am trying to use an API that says it takes a file with the type `string($binary)`. How do I do this? I know this is completely wrong, but here is my code:

```
    def create_extension_zip_file(self, path_to_extension_directory, directory_name):
    zipObj = ZipFile("static_extension.zip", "w")
    with zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path_to_extension_directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                # create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                with open(filename, 'rb') as file_data:
                    bytes_content = file_data.read()
                # Add file to zip
                zipObj.write(bytes_content, basename(filePath))
    return zipObj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if the API expects a file-like object,  you could pass a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instance when creating the zipfile and pass that to the API

```
import io

def create_extension_zip_file(self, path_to_extension_directory, directory_name):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    zipObj = ZipFile(buf, "w")
    with zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path_to_extension_directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                # create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                with open(filename, 'rb') as file_data:
                    bytes_content = file_data.read()
                # Add file to zip
                zipObj.write(bytes_content, basename(filePath))
    # Rewind the buffer's file pointer (may not be necessary)
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf
```

If the API expects a bytes instance, you could just open the zip file in binary mode after it has been written, and pass the bytes .

```
with open('static_extension.zip', 'rb') as f:
    bytes_ = f.read()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like ` zipObj.write(bytes_content, basename(filePath))` works. It says: No such file or direcrory -  b'{...}. Any advice?

Comment: Actually I got it to work useing zipObj.writestr instead of write :) problem is that I get the same error saying it needs to be supported by the buffer api

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to do buf.read() as well. Thanks!